# New battery is not charging on MacBook Pro late 2011

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, macbook-pro

[image: problem]

- New battery
- New AC adapter
- New MagSafe port
- I have voltage in the MagSafe port connector on the logic board
- SMC reset
- GPU switched off

But... no battery charge, no light on the AC adapter's MagSafe connector, can't start without battery.
Plug\unplug charger: https://youtu.be/7rnb9v6DNEo
funny behavior when you turn off/on the charger.

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    D861015004NDGDL3T
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 2
  Hardware Revision:    00aa
  Cell Revision:    2
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   544
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   7800
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  1
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -25
  Voltage (mV): 11350

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    10
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  Current Power Source: Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  0
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    2
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  0

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  Charging: No
```

Comment: Defective motherboard.